# Is it reasonable to avoid explicit calls to Dispose()?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Is it reasonable to make a rule against explicitly calling `Dispose()` on an `IDisposable` object?

Are there any cases where a `using` statement cannot properly ensure an `IDisposable` object is cleaned up?

Comment: As much as I like to let the Garbage Collector manage my memory for me, I have no reservations against calling Dispose() if i have any reason to do so.

Comment: @SamIam: The point of calling Dispose is to free a resource that the memory manager *does not free for you*.  Dispose is explicitly about managing *non memory* resources, so don't bring the memory manager into it at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to make a rule against explicitly calling `Dispose()` on an `IDisposable` object?

No.

> Are there any cases where a `using` statement cannot properly ensure an `IDisposable` object is cleaned up?

There are certainly cases where it makes no sense to use `using` to dispose an object for you. For example, all cases where the desired lifetime of the object is not bound by a particular activation of a method containing a `using` statement.

Consider for example a disposable object which "takes over management" of another disposable object. The "outer" object may well be disposed by a `using` block, but how is the "inner" object, likely stored in a private field of the outer object, to be disposed without an explicit call to `Dispose()`?

Comment: A good, clean answer! I suppose the question bubbled up out of my retired love for C++ and its clean syntax for expressing RAII.

Comment: @NickStrupat: By "clean syntax" you mean "the character `}` causes code to execute". This is not a "clean" syntax, this is a dangerously misleading syntax. The character which demarcates a lexical scope should not be associated with *executable code*; the fact that it is in C++ is one of the design flaws of C++. It continues to be a mystery to me why anyone thinks this is a good idea; if my resource cleanup code is important then I want it to be *explicit* in the code so that I can *read*, *understand* and *debug* it. If it is important, don't hide it.

Comment: @EricLippert - to play devil's advocate, the `}` that closes a `using` block in C# arguably causes code to execute too.  Do you feel that it is "dangerously misleading" syntax, or is the presence of "using" at the start of the block sufficient to excuse it?

Comment: @kvb: The "using" (or the "foreach" or the "lock") clearly calls out that the block that follows it has special semantics.

Comment: @Eric - And in C#, it's necessary for using blocks to be specially marked because their behavior is unusual.  But in C++, stack allocated values are always destroyed at the end their scope, right?  I'm not completely convinced that leaving the destruction implicit is necessarily problematic, but I haven't touched C++ in years so I'll defer to your judgment.

Comment: @kvb: Moreover, "Dispose" semantics are for *politeness* -- to ensure that a scarce resource is cleaned up early. RAII semantics are frequently used to guarantee *correctness*. I say that if a program relies upon a particular function call for its *correctness* then that function call should actually appear somewhere in the program.

Comment: @EricLippert, I think it's not unusual that Dispose is used for correctness. For example, calling `Dipose()` on a `StreamWriter` flushes its buffer. Not calling it (and relying on finalization) means the buffer is never flushed, so the contents of the file are incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases it's simply not possible to avoid an explicit call to `Dispose` and still maintain proper semantics.  For example consider `IDisposable` objects which have a field also of type `IDisposable`.  They must us an explicit call to `Dispose` to dispose the field

```
class Container : IDisposable {
  private readonly IDisposable _field;

  public void Dipose() {

    // Don't want a using here.
    _field.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: well, you COULD still use a using block to trigger the disposal... but it would be weird since it wouldn't match the object's entire lifetime, just its death.  The `using` control expression doesn't have to create the object, it just has to assign a variable.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes you *could* use a using.  It would be a bit of overkill though ;0

Answer (score 3):

One natural assumption is that you can always call `Dispose` on an object, and this will clean up the object's resources, regardless of what state the object is in.

This natural assumption is not always a correct assumption.

An example is with [WCF client proxies.](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2007/11/22/117058.aspx).

The correct way to manage proxy lifetime is as follows:

```
var serviceClient = new sandbox.SandboxServiceClient();
serviceClient.HelloWorld(name);
if(serviceClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
{
    serviceClient.Abort();
}
else
{
    serviceClient.Dispose();
}
```

Switching to the `using` syntax will result in unsafe code:

```
using (var serviceClient = new sandbox.SandboxServiceClient()) 
{
    serviceClient.HelloWorld(name);
}  // Here An exception will be thrown if the channel has faulted
```

You could argue (*as we all do*) that this is a flawed design aspect of WCF, but the reality of programming is that we sometimes have to modify our style to accommodate the frameworks we're using. Here's an example where a blanket rule against explicit `Dispose` cannot apply, even when the lifetime of the object is contained within one function call.

Answer (score 2):

A `using` statement (which really is shorthand for a try/finally with `Dispose` called in the finally block) is for scenarios where you acquire a resource, make use of it, then dispose of it within one same method. If you don't have such a linear usage of the resource (e.g. its usage is split across methods) you will have to call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

If the cost of creating instances of a disposable type is high (e.g. a type which encapsulates a remote connection), you may want to reuse instances to amortize the cost. In that case `using` will not be useful and you'll have to call `Dispose` at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote against such rule, what if you have an object you want to use multiple times across several function calls, a using statement will force the disposal of that object, the next time you want to use it, you have to re-initialize...